# why do std collection iterators use raw pointer + PhantomData instead of normal ref?

Tags: rust

for example, slice Iter https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/slice/iter.rs.html#62 and LinkedList Iter https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/collections/linked_list.rs.html#74

both, rather than storing a normal ref to the struct they iterate over, store raw pointer variants (e.g. NonNull).

I imagine that slice::Iter could instead be built as

```
pub struct Iter<'a, T: 'a> {
  slice_ref: &'a [T],
  current_pos: usize,
}
```

so, why are raw pointers preferred/required here?

Comment: cause mut iterator need unsafe pointer to compile without gats back in 2015

Answer (score 4):

Slice iterators are *very, very* performance sensitive. They're used in pretty much all Rust code out there, and they might be the hottest code in all of std. So their design and implementation was carefully constructed and benchmarked to be the most performant possible, and every change requires a performance measurement.

In particular, the form you're suggesting is pretty bad (even very bad). It increases the fields count, which means more registers are occupied, and it requires an addition (to add the current offset to the beginning of the slice) for each element. Using pointers avoids that.

They could probably use a single slice and advance it, but there are complexities with handling ZSTs, and frankly, it seems just easier to have it all raw pointers.

Comment: Just to drive the point home, compare the assembly of this custom implementation of `std::slice::Iter` (that doesn't even use another field) to the original and you'll see it's doing much more work: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=3c38c3defc541f0e9378d74d7b18c220). (Click the ellipses next to "Build" and select "ASM"). This is because the std iterator uses a representation of `{ start: *const T, end: *const T }`, which isn't possible in safe rust with references, which instead have a representation of `{ start: *const T, len: usize }`.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing the linked-list iterator implementation: You may notice a `LinkedList` [does not use references internally](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/collections/linked_list.rs.html#51-60).

The standard linked-list is doubly-linked - meaning a node in the list is connected to both the next element and previous element - which makes ownership less clear since its by-construction self-referencing. It also must provide mutation of the elements which would entirely prevent internal references altogether. A doubly-linked list simply doesn't mesh well with Rust's ownership model. You can read through [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/index.html) if you want to know more; the final chapter culminates with a design that is pretty much the same as the standard's.

So `LinkedList` uses pointers internally and thus the iterator implementation just follows suit.